# Validate Android NDK compiled library is compiled for correct architecture

Tags: android-ndk

I have a number of libraries built using either CMake or Automake and I'd like to make sure they are compiled correctly for the various architectures. Specifically I'd like to make sure the libraries I targeted for armeabi and armeabi-v7a are compiled with ARM v5 or ARM v7-a instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that `readelf` on linux provides a degree of certainty that the library was compiled with the desired options and you don't need to be on Linux, because the tool is in the NDK. The following examples were compiled with Clang using NDK r13b.

```
# -h option instead of -A is helpful if you're inspecting x86 binaries
arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -A library.so
```

`readelf` is in the NDK toolchain so even if you're on macOS you can still use it.

#### armeabi

```
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "5TE"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v5TE
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-1
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv2
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_optimization_goals: Aggressive Speed
```

#### armeabi-v7a

```
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "ARM v7"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3
  Tag_Advanced_SIMD_arch: NEONv1
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: Deprecated
  Tag_ABI_optimization_goals: Aggressive Speed
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
```